# Whats wrong with this function please?

Tags: wordpress, function, search, posts

I have tried this function in my Wordpress functions file with and without PHP tags. I just get a undefined function error across my site. What am I doing wrong please? It was intended to block pages from my search results leaving on post results.

```
<?php
function mySearchFilter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'post');
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet goes in ones theme functions.php and not the WordPress included functions.php.